# Javafx webkit loading HTML content

Tags: webkit, javafx

I have a javafx application which is loading HTML content using webkit. I have created a stage and a scene and do `webEngine.load(html)`. It works fine. But when I minimize the application and then again maximize it after sometime, the stage shows black screen for 2-3 seconds before loading the html again.

My question is why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Which version of JavaFX and which platform are you using?

Comment: I am using Win 7 64bit with JavaFx 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

You are using very old JavaFX. Can you try with latest version 2.2.21 which can be found here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

It's cobundled with jdk 7u21, just download and install jdk and you get JavaFX with it.